# Where do these 200 mV come from?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I was analyzing a circuit and when simulating it in PSpice I came across this:

[image]

Is there a way of calculating without simulation (i.e. just looking at the circuit and doing the algebra) that \$V_{BE}=-0.2V\$?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: I measured this value in a real circuit and I got the same value, give or take a few mV, so the simulation was pretty accurate.

Comment: No, it cannot be done without the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPICE places a resistor across every p-n junction to aid convergence. The default value is 10^12 ohm (GMIN=1e-12). So, the BC junction has 10^12 ohms across it and this runs a current of about 9V/1e12 = 9 pA. This current flows in R2 (4.7k) giving a calculated 42 nV. Your SPICE may have a different GMIN, and in fact the transistor model will also have B-C junction leakage.

Now, most of this 9 pA will flow in the B-E junction, and the 1e12 across it also (when you calculate, you will find most is in the B-E junction). This would normally also get multiplied by the transistor's beta, but at low currents, the beta falls to low levels -- this is probably why there is 'only' 74 nV across R3.

Anyway, there is about 9 nA in the B-E junction. Consider that this generates 200 mV, and each 60 mV additional raises current 10x (because of the exponential relationship between voltage and current in a diode junction) -- so 200+3*60=380 mV => 9 uA, and 560 mV => 9 mA which are 'reasonable' values for a discrete transistor.

Answer (score 2):

Since C1 is an ideal capacitor, it has infinite resistance, which means no base current. This is supported by the 0 volts across R1. With no base current, there should be virtually no emitter or collector current, and this is supported by the 73 nV on R2. So, the emitter-base voltage is going to be determined by various leakages in the transistor, and these are not well-modelled (although clearly there is something in the Spice model which is producing your 0.2 volts. As a result, G36 is correct - there is no way to do it short of the simulation, and I'll go G36 one better: don't trust the simulation.